# Modifying ViewModel Properties outside of ViewModel - Values aren't saving

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, mvvm-light

Is it possible to modify properties of a ViewModel by using an instance of ViewModelLocator elsewhere in the code? When I try, any value I try to assign seems to be discarded.

For example, a ViewModel, an instance of which named "Game" is contained in my ViewModelLocator. It has a string property named "Test". When I try to modify it this way:

```
(App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).Game.Test = "Testing";
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show((App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).Game.Test);
```

or

```
ViewModelLocator _viewModelLocator = new ViewModelLocator();

_viewModelLocator.Game.Test = "Testing";
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(_viewModelLocator.Game.Test);
```

The messageboxes display the value of the string declared in the ViewModel itself if there is one. If a value hasn't been assigned in the ViewModel, the messageboxes show up empty. Either way, they don't display "Testing".

How can I make this work? I'm using MVVM Light with Unity.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private static Bootstrapper _bootstrapper;

    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        if (_bootstrapper == null)
            _bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
    }

    public GameViewModel Game
    {
        get { return _bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<GameViewModel>(); }
    }
}

public class Bootstrapper
{
    public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Container = new UnityContainer();

        ConfigureContainer();
    }

    private void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<GameViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a problem with Unity. I switched back to MVVM Light's SimpleIoc and it works without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Container.RegisterType<GameViewModel>();` this registers the type `GameViewModel` with the default lifetime manager.  [The default lifetime manager for the RegisterType method is the TransientLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) which means that every time `Resolve` is called a new instance is returned.

So every time the `Game` property is called a new instance of `GameViewModel` is returned.  Any modifications to the object will only be made to that object (and lost when the object is GC'd).  The next time the `Game` property is called a new instance of `GameViewModel` is returned.

So, assuming you only want one `GameViewModel` you should register it as a singleton:

```
private void ConfigureContainer()
{
    Container.RegisterType<GameViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```